# jquery window on load and resize not running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that is used for a responsive image slider that shows the logos of partners.

This is how it looks.
https://i.scrny.me/yaOn.gif

At times, it randomly stops working, i refresh the page a few times and its working again so I am not sure what the problem is. This is how it looks when it stops working.
https://i.scrny.me/ot1N.png

This is the JavaScript code I am using for this.

```
$(function() {
var partnerSlider = $('.partners'),
    partners = partnerSlider.children().length,
    width, partnerHeight, containerWidth, windowSize, columns = 4;

//Making it responsive and all
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
    containerWidth = $('.container').width();
    windowSize = $(window).width();
    if (windowSize >= 992) {
        columns = 4;
    }
    else if (windowSize >= 768 && windowSize < 992) {
        columns = 3;
    }
    else if (windowSize < 768) {
        columns = 2;
    }

    $('#partners').css('width', containerWidth);
    $('.partner').css('width', containerWidth / columns);
    width = containerWidth / columns;
    partnerHeight = $('.partner > img').height() + 20;
    partnerSlider.css({width: (partners * width), height: partnerHeight});
});

var rotating = true;
var sliderSpeed = 4000;
var seePartners = setInterval(slidePartners, sliderSpeed);

$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        rotating = false;
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        rotating = true;
    }
}, '.partners');

function slidePartners() {
    if (rotating !== false) {
        var first = $('.partner:first');
        first.animate({'margin-left': '-'  + width + 'px'}, 1000, function () {
            first.remove().css({'margin-left': '0px'});
            $('.partner:last').after(first);
        });
    }
}

});
```

As far as I managed to figure out the problem is from this part.

```
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
containerWidth = $('.container').width();
windowSize = $(window).width();
if (windowSize >= 992) {
    columns = 4;
}
else if (windowSize >= 768 && windowSize < 992) {
    columns = 3;
}
else if (windowSize < 768) {
    columns = 2;
}

$('#partners').css('width', containerWidth);
$('.partner').css('width', containerWidth / columns);
width = containerWidth / columns;
partnerHeight = $('.partner > img').height() + 20;
partnerSlider.css({width: (partners * width), height: partnerHeight});
});
```

The function is meant to run whenever the page is loaded or resized I believe but sometimes when the page is loaded it doesn't run so it does not automatically assign the sizes for the images and the container.

This is the HTML

```
<div class="container wow fadeIn" style="overflow:hidden;">
    <h2>Partners</h2>
    <div class="partners">
        <div class="partner">
            <img src="assets/images/sponsor.png" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="partner">
            <img src="assets/images/sponsor.png" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="partner">
            <img src="assets/images/sponsor.png" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="partner">
            <img src="assets/images/sponsor.png" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="partner">
            <img src="assets/images/sponsor.png" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="partner">
            <img src="assets/images/sponsor.png" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
        <div class="partner">
            <img src="assets/images/sponsor.png" class="img-responsive"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the basics of what the html looks like.

Comment: Sorry about that, added the HTML.

Comment: What about CSS? I made JSFiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/urkj8euj/3/

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Besides referencing your partners div by id instead of class I can't really see any reason that it would be failing. If it's failing on IE it might be because of the `setInterval` function, it causes memory leaks in IE.

Comment: I am using jquery version 3.2.1 and I use Google Chrome not IE.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue with your code is related to the version of jQuery you have. Sometime within the jQuery 3.x.x version (not sure when exactly) changes were made to make the on ready event handlers run asynchronously. This means there can be scenarios where the on `load` event completes before the `ready` event is fired. In you case, this becomes an issue because if the `load` event has been fired before `ready` is called, the `window.load` event handlers registered inside jQuery's `document.ready()` will not run. This sequence can depend on many things like how quickly the page loads, image caching..., which is why you see the issue occurring inconsistently.

The solution is to update the code you have and move the `$(window).('on')` event handler outside the docuemnt.ready function: `$(function(){})`. Additionally, since I didn't see it in the jsFiddle you provided, make sure the scripts for your js code are embedded withing the `<body>` element, as this is the ideal place to put code that impacts the rendering of the page.

I've update teh jsfiddle provided to include these changes, take a look:

**[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urkj8euj/19/)**

Comment: Hey Sasang, thanks for the answer. I have already fixed this issue by making a function called `partnerSize` in this function I put all the code that was previously inside the `$(window).on(...)`  and now I run this function once when the page is loaded and also put the function call inside `$(window).on("resize", function()` It seems to have fixed the problem. I have my Javascript code in a global script.js file which is why it is inside a `$(function () {});` .